# How do I make it so my iPhone app requires a 4 inch screen or larger?

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist, screen-size

How do I make it so my iPhone app requires a 4 inch screen or larger? Is it possible using the plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. If your app runs on iOS 8/9, it runs on an iPhone 4s which has a 3.5-inch screen. Change your desires plist, not your app plist.